# Do I need the same IDE if I am using GitHub for two different computers?

Tags: java, github

I have a laptop and a desktop. I prefer using my desktop when I am at home working with my school projects.

If I upload everything on GitHub with my laptop and I'm using Eclipse or Intellij, do I need to use the same IDE/IDEA to continue working on my projects at home?

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: For Java projects use Maven. Both IDE's understand Maven. Remember to "ignore" the custom IDE files, such as `.project` etc.

Comment: While certainly possible, it might be difficult to get the project to build the same way on both systems.  Lots of people use multiple IDEs, but that introduces an additional source of potential problems.  As a relative beginner I'd avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 6):

No you don't need to use the same IDE. But be careful, different ide's have different files that should not go to git. IntelliJ produces `.iml` files and Eclipse produce `.project` files. Some other files might also exist and you may not want them to go git. So, you need to define your `.gitignore` files carefully and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you decide to upload IDE specific configurations into your source control, or if you don't use something like Maven or Gradle to manage your source dependencies, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

IDE has nothing to do with your code or the machine you use, there are many IDEs you can choose from based on your personal preferences like visual-studio, Atom, sublime, notepad++ e.t.c. sure few people associate an IDE with particular language/framework, then again there is no standard for this, everyone has there own preference.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use same IDE. The two you mentioned has property of connecting git so you can just go as you want. Just import your projects from git.